# SQL Server AVG Functions Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

I have two SQL Server tables...

```
MODULES        ENROLMENTS
GroupNo        StudentNo
Title          GroupNo
Tutor          CourseworkMark
DayNo          ExamMark
Time
Room
Semester
```

In Access I have created a form based on another table which holds records of course numbers and names. For each course, I wish to create a subform about the modules within that particular course.

In the subform view I wish to have GroupNo, Title, Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester, Average of CourseworkMark and Average of ExamMark.

I have constructed this query

```
SELECT tblEnrolments.GroupNo, Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester, 
       AVG(CourseworkMark) AS AvgCourseworkMark, AVG(ExamMark) AS AvgExamMark
FROM tblEnrolments INNER JOIN tblModules ON tblEnrolments.GroupNo = tblModules.GroupNo
GROUP BY tblEnrolments.GroupNo;
```

however, I get the error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'tblModules.Tutor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

when I run it. How do I get the Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room and Semester fields in the query as they are not part of the GROUP BY or AVG. Thank you

Comment: You need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the `group by`.  The error message seems pretty clear to me.  If that doesn't solve your problem, you should include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Add `Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester` to the group by clause.

Comment: Your title says "SQL Server".  Your question says "Access".  Which is it?

Comment: Ah duhhh didn't think to try that. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by all values in your select list , so the query will look like :

```
SELECT tblEnrolments.GroupNo, Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester, 
       AVG(CourseworkMark) AS AvgCourseworkMark, AVG(ExamMark) AS AvgExamMark
FROM tblEnrolments INNER JOIN tblModules ON tblEnrolments.GroupNo = tblModules.GroupNo
GROUP BY tblEnrolments.GroupNo, Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester;
```

Answer (score 0):

As this error saying

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'tblModules.Tutor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

and also mention in the comment
`@Gordon Linoff:`

**You need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the group by**

```
SELECT tblEnrolments.GroupNo, 
                     Tutor, 
                     DayNo, 
                     Time, 
                     Room, 
                     Semester, 
                     AVG(CourseworkMark) AS AvgCourseworkMark, 
                     AVG(ExamMark) AS AvgExamMark
FROM tblEnrolments 
INNER JOIN tblModules ON tblEnrolments.GroupNo = tblModules.GroupNo
GROUP BY tblEnrolments.GroupNo ,Tutor, DayNo, Time, Room, Semester ;
```